# Search enable on press of enter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a search textbox which has some restrictions that it should not allow special characters, but on click of enter key it should redirect to the search page for the respective search. I have added the code for regex for not allowing special characters, but how should I achieve that it should redirect to the proper search page on click of enter when user types search.

My result search page name is `search.aspx`. Please see the JS code for your reference.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#ctl00_topNavigation_txtSearch').bind('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\b _ _%]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your keypress event

```
var searchUrl = "search.aspx?tx=" + ctl00_topNavigation_txtSearch.val();

window.location.replace(searchUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keycode for enter is 13, so just add a check if keycode was 13, if yes then redirect the user

```
function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        //code to redirect goes here
        //window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
        return false;
    }
        return true;
});
```

Comment: is this should be my the redirection code.
'search.aspx?tx=' + ctl00_topNavigation_txtSearch.Text  but its not taking me properly

Comment: when i add that, my regex functionality stops working. Please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qxmRq/

Comment: You used my code as it is, it's a sample :) You already have the keycode value in your code, just put a `if` condition on it to check against `13` and then use `window.location.href`.